# How can I load image through api by using external image url?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-images, rest-api

I have my product images in my cloud store and those are public. I want to map those images to product through API. I have gone through the solution given in the below link. But I want to check if there is a way to specify a downloadable link in the payload and the Magento server would download the image in the system, So that I don't have to send image data through the payload.
[Magento 2 - How to upload image to REST API (POST)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180128/magento-2-how-to-upload-image-to-rest-api-post)

I understand that when we specify the image url in the product csv and import the file, magento does download it and display it on the product page. I want to use similar functionality through the API.

NOTE: I am working on java and I want to use magento 2 apis to do this. Basically I am looking for correct API call (if any) which will automatically load the image into Magento store by downloading it from the cloud store.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code can help to get your desired result:

```
<?php
/**
 * file location:
 * app/code/VendorName/ExtensionName/Service/ImportImageService.php
 */

namespace VendorName\ExtensionName\Service;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File;

/**
 * Class ImportImageService
 * assign images to products by image URL
 */
class ImportImageService
{
    /**
     * Directory List
     *
     * @var DirectoryList
     */
    protected $directoryList;

    /**
     * File interface
     *
     * @var File
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * ImportImageService constructor
     *
     * @param DirectoryList $directoryList
     * @param File $file
     */
    public function __construct(
        DirectoryList $directoryList,
        File $file
    ) {
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * Main service executor
     *
     * @param Product $product
     * @param string $imageUrl
     * @param array $imageType
     * @param bool $visible
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function execute($product, $imageUrl, $visible = false, $imageType = [])
    {
        /** @var string $tmpDir */
        $tmpDir = $this->getMediaDirTmpDir();
        /** create folder if it is not exists */
        $this->file->checkAndCreateFolder($tmpDir);
        /** @var string $newFileName */
        $newFileName = $tmpDir . baseName($imageUrl);
        /** read file from URL and copy it to the new destination */
        $result = $this->file->read($imageUrl, $newFileName);
        if ($result) {
            /** add saved file to the $product gallery */
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($newFileName, $imageType, true, $visible);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Media directory name for the temporary file storage
     * pub/media/tmp
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getMediaDirTmpDir()
    {

        return $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tmp';
    }
}
```

> **Credit**: https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/import-product-image-from-url/

Comment: Hello Amit, thanks for the response. But I am working on java and I am using magento  2 apis to do this. Basically I am looking for correct API call (if any) which will automatically load the image into Magento store.